# MariaDB multiple masters in JDBC connection string

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mariadb

I am using MariaDB 5.5.38 and JDBC driver for MySQL. According to [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html) I should use connection string like

```
jdbc:mysql://address=(type=master)(host=master1host),address=(type=master)(host=master2host)/db
```

to use several master hosts. But when I use it I get `NullPointerException` in `com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.parseHostPortPair(NonRegisteringDriver.java:216) [mysql.mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]`. I also use connection pool from Apache Commons, but I think it's not relevant. So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to specify the host as a host/port pair? eg (host=master1host:3089)?

Comment: I use the same port for every host, so I think it doesn't matter.

Comment: Does it work if you point it at a single host?

Comment: No. I tried jdbc:mysql://address=(type=master)(host=localhost)(port=3306)/db and it threw the mentioned exception.

Comment: I can confirm this happens also with vanilla mysql Mysqlconnector J following this docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html in my case both connections are localhost but different port and NPE still present. But one is master the other is slave, i pressume it has nothing to do with both connections being master

Comment: After browsing mysqlconnectorj sourcecode what you are missing is the replication or loadbalance prefix to the connection url: "jdbc:mysql:replication//...." or "jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://...."

Answer (score 1):

Your link to [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html) describe a Master/Slave setup.

If you want multi master setup you can use this url:

`jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://masterHost1,masterHost2/db`

Read more about it here: [Configuring Load Balancing with Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-managing-load-balanced-connections.html)

Comment: The point is that I don't need load balancer - I have it already.

Comment: I am just curious: Why do you want multi master? How is the loadbalancer working today?

Answer (score 0):

After browsing mysql-connector-j source code NPE is caused by a missing prefix on your connection URL. It should be one of the following:

```
jdbc:mysql:loadbalance//.....
jdbc:mysql:replication//.....
```

With this urls it seems only urls with //host:port,host:port/db work and only the first one is used as a master.

other thing to check is what Driver class are you using.

acording to this question: [How do I configure our MySQL ReplicationDriver for our JBoss 7 data source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299210/how-do-i-configure-our-mysql-replicationdriver-for-our-jboss-7-data-source)

the correct class is

```
com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the following:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75440

I changed the connection url to:

```
jdbc:mysql://address=(protocol=tcp)(type=master)(host=serv1),address=(protocol=tcp)(type=master)(host=serv2)/db
```

this works for me so far